# How can I convert a text string to hour format with python

Tags: python

I need to convert a text string `'2017-08-09T15: 00: 39.000Z'` to hour format, to do operations with it

Comment: `from datetime import datetime; datetime.strptime('2017-08-09T15: 00: 39.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H: %M: %S.%fZ')`.

Comment: Get the following error 

"ValueError: time data '2017-08-09T15:00:39.000Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H: %M: %S.%fZ'"

Comment: That's because the string you posted here is different from the one you're working with in your console. The whitespace characters matter very much: Try `from datetime import datetime; datetime.strptime('2017-08-09T15:00:39.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')`.